# navigator.clipboard.write to copy image clipboard in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, clipboard

I am taking screenshot of webpage using html2canvas and then copy the content to clipboard using `navigator.clipboard.write` and `ClipboardItem`. This works fine on chrome

```
tempCanvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    navigator.clipboard
        .write([
        new ClipboardItem(
            Object.defineProperty({}, blob.type, {
                value: blob,
                enumerable: true
            })
        )
    ]).then(function() {
        console.log( "Copied to clipboard");
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work on Firefox and Safari

I was trying

```
tempCanvas.toBlob(function(blob) { 
    let data   = new DataTransfer();
    data.items.add("image/jpeg", blob);
    navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(function() {
        console.log( "Copied to clipboard");
    });
});
```

Seems not working.

Comment: One year later, same problem, same question.
The problem comes from the fact that ClipboardItem is not Firefox-compatible (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem).
But how to do the copy without a ClipboardItem? Can someone help here?